# Im trying to re-create a table view from one screen to another but keep getting the error signal sigbart

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

I'm creating a simple app. I'm trying to make two screens look the same but I can't seem to get one of the table views to work. Instead, when the set up table view function is called, the error signal sigbart appears. I can't see why this is since on the other screen the table view works no problem and I've copied over the code.

```
let tableview: UITableView = {
    let tv = UITableView()

    tv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return tv
}()

func setupTableView() {
    tableview.delegate = self
    tableview.dataSource = self

    tableview.register(BunchCells.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")

    tableview.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)

    view.addSubview(tableview)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        tableview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 170),
        tableview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
        tableview.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor),
        tableview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor)
    ])
}

class BunchCells: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let cellView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return view
    }()

    let dayLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Day 1"
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return label
    }()    

    func setupView() {
        addSubview(cellView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cellView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            cellView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -10),
            cellView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 10),
            cellView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
        ])

        dayLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        dayLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        dayLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        dayLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellView.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: On the second screen do you create `let tableview: UITableView ` again, or you pass if from the first one?

Comment: I create it again.

Comment: Your code looks all right, can your share your project with us, so we could fully understand what is going on?

Comment: sorry, I'm new to here. How do i share the project? through gitHub?

Comment: Yeah, it would be perfect.

Comment: https://github.com/Hubster888/EasyTask  Here you go. Sorry in advance if its a bit messy, this is the first time I'm using gitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run your program and doesn't have any error, but I think this looks a little bit weird:

```
weak var tableView: UITableView!

let tableview: UITableView = {
    let tv = UITableView()
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tv.separatorColor = UIColor.white
    return tv
}()
```

Maybe cause of your error was what you accidentally invoke method on `tableView` which is always `nil`.? If it is not, give some hints how to reproduce your error).

Comment: Sorry I probably should of said. The error comes up when I press on the calendar tab and then the button that said "Current". I've been playing around with it and think the error comes up when the setupTableView() function runs. Could you try that and see if the error comes up for you.

Comment: Yeah error occurs, but it is due to the not connected outlets, https://www.dropbox.com/s/uxv43824vw1trca/Screenshot%202019-07-07%20at%2000.20.39.png?dl=0, you should click on your VC on your storyboard  -> Connection Inspector Tab, and remove these connections.

Comment: I've removed all connections on that VC but the signal SIGBART still comes up.

Comment: But what is in the stack trace (Console Output)? It is? `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7fbad1c2ce00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key DateLabel.`

Comment: So does this mean there is still a connection that I need to remove? If so I cant see where.

Comment: Did you make any changes?

Comment: Now I get the error: reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600003ef9f40 "UILabel:0x7fa9ad018c80'Day 1'.left"> and <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600003ef97c0 "UIView:0x7fa9ad0168e0.left"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'      . I think I know what it means but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: No I didn't do any changes, I just removed outlet connections, now again how to reproduce your error, and where did you get that error? ;d

Comment: I think I've found the solution.  Underv setupView() I needed to do cellView.addSubview(dayLabel)    This way the constraints are activated after the label is added. Therefore the SIGBART error stops coming up.

Comment: if your problem is resolved, do not forget to close your issue by accepting an answer :D